# How to create an interface with keys based on values from an array

Tags: typescript

I have a function which takes in an object and an array of strings. It then returns a new object with only the keys from the original object which is specified in the said array.

How do I go about to type this object in typescript?
I would like to initialize the new object with an interface derived from the array, or at least be able to properly type the returned object. I might be way of, and there are probably better ways to go about doing this, but any suggestions?

```
    function myFunction(person: Person, wantedKeys: string[]) {    
            const wantedObject = {} as any; // <-- current workaround
            wantedKeys.forEach(key => (wantedObject[key] = person[key]));
            return wantedObject as Object; // <-- current workaround needs typing
    }
```

Comment: Are `wantedKeys` actually known at build time?

Comment: @spender Yes they are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by the definition of [`Pick<T, K>`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1492), I believe that the following function satisfies your requirements:

```
const pickObj = <T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, keys: readonly K[]): { [P in K]: T[P] } =>
    Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [k, obj[k]])) as { [P in K]: T[P] };
```

Now you can:

```
const myObj = {
    a: "a",
    b: "b",
    c: "c"
}

const newObj = pickObj(myObj, ["a", "b"])

console.log(newObj)
/* 
   {
    "a": "a",
    "b": "b"
   } 
*/
```

enjoying type-safety in the keys parameter and a correctly inferred return-type.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgS2AawPICMBWMC8MA8AKgDQwDSMApgB5SVgAmEMylAniAGYyEB8AFCCwAuHqVZsIogE6UAhg3AAbNuQDaAXQCUogN4w1ABRgIw5DaMJGNMAL65eAKBguYGTJWBQAdJ2kgAWwBRMChpBEoIfgkIbwC5OGiHA2RSIUw1ZA1tLRg5Zn0jEzMyCx5rOwBuR0dQSFgAtndcGF1nVzlRACI5LuJ2l3Ru9D6BmGBu4C7HWxq66BgwSgB3ZrxEFHd+RvdSNR6+mC6R7TnwCBAlSm8lEABzfiXVrC0gA)